# Determining whether pagebreak will occur

Tags: page-breaking, tex-core

So this question is more about the point and the inner workings of TeX instead of a practical solution.
How does LaTeX (or TeX?) determine, whether a pagebreak occurs (I mean the stretch-y/ fluid type bevor headings etc., not when the page is full)?
It's obviously deterministic, so what's the algorithm? Can I reproduce it in a TeX macro, to check whether a pagebreak will occure given a certain further input to the current output?

Consider this MWE using the pagebreak penalty explicitly:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[3]
\pagebreak % Pagebreak does occur here instead of later, comment out to see %
\section{Heading}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Now consider this slightly modified MWE for a "natural" break

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[4]
This is just some text to fill something.\\
This is just some text to fill something.\\
This is just some text to fill something.\\
This is just some text to fill something.\\
\section{Heading}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

I have some programming experience (incl some packages, classes for LaTeX), but haven't looked in depth at the LaTeX, TeX inner workings. I'd appreciate any general answer/ pointing to code bits.

Again, I am not looking for a way to react to a pagebreak, but check upfront.

Comment: You can not re-create all the calculation via tex macros (it is done by tex-the-program not by latex)  you can approximate the calculation (see for example the `needspace` package but some details such as the remaining size of split footnotes is not directly available. also if the page break occurs mid-paragraph, any macros will be expanded while the pararaph is being set in horizontal mode, but line breaking, and so page breaking happens later.

Comment: I think you're just looking for a general understanding of how page breaking works, is that right? See _The TeXBook_ Chapter 15 (“How TeX Makes Lines into Pages”) or _TeX By Topic_ Chapter 27 (“Page Breaking”). The latter is free; you can read it by invoking `texdoc texbytopic` or [online](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Yes, thanks. It certainly helped in understanding.